# How can I recognise which area of an image (not just coordinates) has been touched in Android?

Tags: android, view, bitmap, touch

I am currently developing an Android application for my final year project which should help autistic people indicate when something hurts and do so by touching a picture of the human body.

The problem I've encountered is I don't know how to identify the part of the image they touch. The image is a bitmap, held as a BitmapDrawable in an ImageView. First time is touched, it zooms in via an animation and setFilledAfter(true), and from there when an area is touched the app is supposed to recognize main parts of the body (e.g. head, left hand...).

The areas to be recognized aren't square so checking for coordinates is not really an option. I was thinking along the lines of having each part to be recognised as a different view drawn on top of the original picture, but I'm open too other solutions.

To make things a little bit more interesting the app should work on different devices and resolutions, in both mobiles and tablets.

Thank you so very much in advance for your help. It's really needed and appreciated.

EDIT

In the end what I will be trying is the following. I am going to have two copies of the image, one for display purposes, another internal, with the areas I want recognized painted in different colors. So the plan is to extrapolate the coordinates I obtain from the Touch event to find out to what pixel it corresponds to in regards to the original, the use Bitmap.getPixel() to determine waht color it is, then have a case statement returning the String of each part.

I am coding this right now, if anyone is interested leave a message and I will post how everything worked out, and I someone asks for it even the appropiate code :D

Thanks to Shade for giving me some other options to consider.

Comment: @user647899, a really nice idea! Do post your solution so that others may benefit from it if they bump into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Without having thought too much about this, it seems that your idea - to detect touches with overlay Views - seems to be good.

Apart from that, coordinates are also a good idea - you just have to define named areas of the image and check if the point of touch is within a certain area. Could be a bit more tedious, but may be better in terms of complexity when compared to having 20 views. It will also definitely be faster than adding 20 extra views in your application.

But above all, I think that you should experiment and see what is suitable to your concrete situation, because all else is guesswork.

EDIT:

If you do choose to use the polygon method, then you will have to deal with the problem of determining whether a point is inside of a polygon ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for a short explanation).

Also, regarding Views, a View in Android is defined as a "rectangular area that occupies space on the screen". So that eliminates the possibility of non-rectangular Views. Perhaps there is the possibility of you defining a non-rectangular clickable area inside of a View, but I don't know if that is at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My problem with both solutions is that the areas aren't square (nor rectangular), so coordinates would be really problematic (try to define a hand as sets of coordinates...). Similarly I don't know how to define Views in android which are not rectangular, and even if there's a way, how would I go about to display them? I mean, how can I position each of this views correctly on top of the zoomed in View? Thanks again.

Comment: @user647899, see my edit. I think that this problem should be dealt with in another question here, depending on which approach you choose to use. There have already been questions on SO about the PIP problem, so you can just search.

Comment: @user647899, if my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as the selected answer for the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shade. Your help is much appreciated, though I don't think I will be going down the PIP route, basically because the images I am working with are bitmaps and I'd have to redraw them as polygons. It did make for a very interesting read though. I think I have figured a way to make work without too much hassle. Look at my edit to see what I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, thank you for your idea, it's helped me. That's my implementation of your solution

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
    imgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        switch(action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            int color = bMap.getPixel(x, y) ;
            ImageView testimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
            switch(color) {
            case Color.RED:
                testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.red));
                break;
            case Color.BLUE:
                testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.blue));
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int x1 = (int)event.getX();
            int y1 = (int)event.getY();
            color = bMap.getPixel(x1, y1) ;
            testimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
            testimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.draw);
            // TODO: Rename constant upper-case.
            final int red = 1;
            final int blue = 2;
            switch(color){
            case Color.RED:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(NewActivity.EXT_COLOR, red);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case Color.BLUE:
                i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(NewActivity.EXT_COLOR, blue);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int)event.getY();
            testimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
            color = bMap.getPixel(x, y);
            switch(color){
            case Color.RED:
                testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.red));
                break;
            case Color.BLUE:
                testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.blue));
                break;
            default:
                testimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
                testimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.draw);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```